# Variable From Other Script Sometimes not Loading

Tags: javascript

I have Two JavaScript scripts linked to my HTML File in this order:

```
<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
```

first.js has a variable which is accessed by second.js. The Variable is Used by second.js at the end of the file and the variable is defined in first.js at the beginning. Whenever I reload the site, a console error occasionally comes up saying that the Variable in first.js is not defined.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dbis not defined
> at second.js:80

Why is this? Thanks in Advance.

Full Example:

first.js:

```
var db = [{name: "Obj1", property: "property1"}, {name: "Obj2", property: "property2"}]; // At Line 8
```

second.js:

```
function loadDbItems() {
    for(i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
        console.log(db[i].name); // Line is Near End of Script
    }
}
```

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of the issue? Specifically how the variable is created in `first.js` and how it's used in `second.js`

Comment: Done - Added An Example

Comment: Is the variable in first.js that you're trying to access in second.js wrapped in `{}` at all (are you sure its in the global scope?)

Comment: I am able to access a function which is right after the variable declaration, without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the variable with `window` to make it global guaranteed.
See script example below.

You should not pollute the `window` object with every little variable you need, but this way the variable will exist across scripts, provided the first one executes first.

```js
window.db = [{name: "Obj1", property: "property1"}, {name: "Obj2", property: "property2"}];
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="loadDbItems()">
    <script>
      function loadDbItems() {
        for(var i = 0; i < window.db.length; i++) {
            console.log(window.db[i].name);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```